# Software updates cannot be installed

Tags: software-installation, updates

Whenever software updater pops up in my notifications and I try to install it, after a few moments, it stops itself showing the message

> Failed to download repository information, check your internet connection.

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images when you can post the text inside code tags. Particularly in this situation you obscured the most important parts, the error messages. That said, change the server, try again. If the problem persists make sure to edit the question accordingly and taking into consideration what I commented in the beginning.

Comment: The repository mirror that is selected in the Ubuntu Software tab is down.